# WriteableBitmap Transform to Center?

Tags: c#, silverlight, transform, centering, writeablebitmap

I need to put an user control (a TextBlock in this case) in the horizontal center of a WriteableBitmap, here is the code that i come with so far:

```
textblock1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
wp.Render(textblock1, new TranslateTransform() {Y = topMargin, X = imgWidth / 2});
```

but it appears that the pivot point of the textblock is still at the left edge of the control, where did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be transforming by the center, but the TranslateTransform moves the center the same distance as any other point. It's like grabbing a piece of paper and moving it an inch left. It doesn't matter where you grab it.

Try this:

```
wp.Render(textBlock1, new TranslateTransform() {Y = topMargin - textBlock1.Height / 2, X = imgWidth / 2 - textBlock1.Width / 2});
```

You can forget about RenderTransformOrigin unless you are using rotates/scales/matrices etc.

Comment: I tried that before, and it ended up left-aligned...
i think its because the Width of the TextBlock isnt explicitly assigned, because the content of the TextBlock will be taken from an input in a TextBox

Comment: Does textBlock1.Width == 0? This might happen if it wasn't actually part of the GUI tree (forget the real name right now).

Comment: Yes, its not part of the VisualTree.
anyway, nevermind that, just solved it by setting the Width of the TextBlock to the imgWidth, and set its allignment to center, then it will go to the horizontal center without transform.
shame on me for not realizing this sooner. Thanks! :)

Comment: I was about to suggest calling Measure and then using DesiredSize, but your fix is just as good.